# How can you handle 3 conflicting versions of the same library in a Vite project?

Tags: javascript, three.js, svelte, vite, dependency-management

I have the following odd situation: I am developing a web app with Vite and the svelte-ts template setup. In this app, I have to use different libraries for WebXR based augmented reality, so you can easily switch between them (on different pages, or svelte components responding to different routes in this case) and compare them.

The problem is, all of them depend on different versions of THREE.js.

- The first option is obviously the newest version of `THREE.js` itself.
- The second option is `A-Frame`, which uses not even a different version but a forked version of THREE called "`super-three`" but responding to the same global THREE variable/context.
- The third option is `ModelViewer`, which also uses THREE but an older version of it.

I cannot install them all into the same node_modules folder via npm as they will cause conflicts with their dependencies. Using "`--legacy-peer-deps`" or "`--force`" options for npm install will not work, as i cannot force them to use one specific version (which with super-three doesnt work anyway).

I cannot use import aliases, because for A-Frame and ModelViewer i cannot change how they internally and globally access THREE. There is shared code I need for the genera app and for all the 3 webxr components to access. I tried going for a monorepo setup where each webxr component is its own submodule with own node_modules folder with a "shared" folder in the root level, but it kept installing everything into the root level node_modules causing the same issues. It needs to be one deployable app.

```
- / (root level)
   - node_modules/
   - packages/
     - three/
       - src/
       - package.json
       - ...
     - aframe/
       - src/
       - package.json
       - ...
     - model-viewer/
       - src/
       - package.json
       - ...
   - shared
     - src
     - package.json
     - ...remaining vite, typescript and svelte stuff
```

I also tried writing my entire app in svelte, but then have the 3 webxr pages just be static html pages i link to where the deps are loaded via `<script></script>` tags, but then i cannot use and import my shared code there. I suppose i would have to precompile it into some standard `shared.js` file that is then included and used both by my svelte component code and the static independent pages?

Dynamic imports also don't work as they still require the dependencies first to be installed in the `node_modules` folder, where they conflict. How do i solve this so i still have one deployable app?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you create four Vite projects and use `single-spa` in ES modules (see about my plug-in, `vite-plugin-single-spa`).  With independent projects, you install the version of `three.js` that you need without conflicts.  Each one of these would be `single-spa` *micro-frontend* projects.

The fourth project would be the `single-spa` root project and would load the micro-frontend that matches the user's choice.

Up to this point, your requirement should be satisfied, except for the "one deployable app" requirement.

At this point you would need to decide:  "Can I live with 4 deployments?"  If yes, you're done.  Set up 4 deployments of 4 distinct projects as per `single-spa`'s architecture.

If you replied "No", then work on creating a single deployment.  As you probably know, Vite's output is a static website (static files).  Build each project, then collect the build results into one server deployment and voilá.